# sass list media query with variables

Tags: sass

it gives me error while using this mixin! and points to "nth" of the last condition, error is included at last.

```
@mixin break($para...) {
    @if($para==1) {
        @media (max-width: nth($para, 1)) {
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media (min-width: nth($para, 1)) and (max-width: nth($para, 2)) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

Compilation Error
Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`
        on line 42 of sass/e:\coding\sass\scss\pro\assets\css\-mixins.scss, in function `nth`
        from line 42 of sass/e:\coding\sass\scss\pro\assets\css\-mixins.scss, in mixin `break`
        from line 15 of sass/e:\coding\sass\scss\pro\assets\css\main.scss
>> min-width: nth($para, 1)) and (max-width: nth($para, 2)) {
   ------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: How are you using the mixin? I guess you are not passing enough arguments.

Comment: $para...
using the 3 dots !

 By using ... in the signature, we make it possible to pass any number of arguments, from none to a bazillon. It shares the exact same traits with a regular list, except that it is always comma-separated since several arguments are delimited by commas.

Comment: Yes, I know. I asked because it works on my side (I only tried with two arguments). After checking again, it seems that the problem comes from your `@if` condition. It should be `length($para) == 1`. Currently it always go in the `@else` so if you pass only one argument `nth($para, 2)` can't work and thus return an error.

Comment: Great! I will post this as an answer then as comments shouldn't be used for this purpose.

Comment: of course you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the `@if` condition which should be `length($para) == 1` instead of `$para==1`. Otherwise, it will always go in the `@else` statement and if there is only one argument passed to the mixin `nth($para, 2)` returns an error.